# MySQL 5.6 with GTID -> MariaDB 10.1

Tags: mysql, mariadb, gtid

I have a MySQL 5.6 database with enabled GTIDs.

Is it possible to simply remove MySQL, install MariaDB and run it on the same binary files?

I know that MariaDB GTID technology is not compatible with MySQL's one, but I can't find anyone who tried to test this case.

Comment: which binary file do you mean ? datafile (ibd) or Programm

Comment: The data files are compatible.  The binlog/relaylog may be an issue.  Are you using Master-Slave now?  Is the binlog turned on?  GTID only applies to replication (and, hence, the binlog), not data storage (tables, ibdata1, etc).

Comment: I mean data files, thanks. I'm using master-slave replication now and binlog is turned on with GTIDs.